# Closed subset of Banach space containing unit ball.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

> Problem: Let $X$ be a real Banach Space, and $A$ be a closed nonempty
>   subset of $X$ such that (i) $A$ is closed under addition (ii) closed
>   under positive scalar multiplication, i.e., $\lambda x \in A$,
>   $\forall x \in A$ and $\forall \lambda >0$, and (iii) $\forall x \in
> X$, $\exists x_{1}, x_{2} \in A$ such that $x = x_{1}-x_{2}$.
>
> Then, $\exists C>0$ such that the unit ball $B(0,1)$ is contained in
>   the closure of $\mathcal{A} =\{ x_{1} - x_{2} : x_{i} \in A, ||x_{i}||
> \leq M : i =1,2 \},$

My attempt: First of all, $0 \in A$ since $A$ is closed and $<\lambda x>$ converges to $0$ for some element $x \in A$. Also, from $span(A) = X$, $A$ should contain a basis, say $\mathcal{B}$. Using dilation with positive constant, we may assume that $\mathcal{B}$ is normal, i.e., has norm 1. (We cannot use Gram-schimdt process because $A$ is not closed under subtraction.) Say $\mathcal{B} = \{e_{\alpha} \}_{\alpha \in I}$ for some index set $I$.

If $X$ is finite dimensional space with dimension $n$, then $M = 1$ gives desired answer, by drawing carefully; for example, if $ x\in \mathbb{R}^{2}$, draw two lines containing $x$ and having $e_{1}$ and $e_{2}$ as its direction respectively. Also, draw two lines containing origin and having $e_{1}$ and $e_{2}$ as its direction respectively. Intersection of those lines give two vectors which is dilation of $e_{1}$ and $e_{2}$.

I think the similar thing happens in the arbitrary Banach space, but I was stuck to generalize my construction in the infinite vector space. Could anyone gives me hint to prove this problem?

Second Attempt:

By hint from @ProjectBook, I think we can use the Baire Category Theorem. Let $A_{n} = \{ x_{1} - x_{2} : x_{i} \in A \cap \overline{B(0,n)}\}$. Since $\forall y  \in A \cap \overline{B(0,n)}$, $||y|| \leq n$ implies
$$A_{n} = \{ x_{1} - x_{2} : x_{i} \in A \cap \overline{B(0,n)}\}= \{x_{1}-x_{2} : x_{i} \in A , ||x_{i}|| \leq n , i =1,2 \}. $$

Then, $\forall x \in X$, $x=x_{1}-x_{2}$ for some $x_{1},x_{2} \in A$, and since they have finite norm, $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $||x_{i}|| \in N$ for $i=1,2$, thus $x \in A_{N}$. This implies $$X = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}$$
By the Baire Category theorem with the fact that $X$ is Banach space, there exists a nonmeager set $A_{n}$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Since $\{A \cap \overline{B(0,n)}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is nested sequence, for all $m>n$, $A_{m}$ is of second category.

Question: I think I can solve this theorem without using Baire category theorem. Suppose, to get contradiction, that there is no $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $B(0,1) \not\subseteq \bigcup_{j=1}^{n}A_{j}$. Then, this implies $B(0,1) \not\subseteq \bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}A_{j} = X$, contradiction. Thus, $\exists M \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $B(0,1) \subseteq A_{M}$.

Is this correct or am I missing something in the proof?

Comment: Banach category.

Comment: @ProjectBook Thank you! I will find what it is and how to apply to this problem.

Comment: @ProjectBook If you don't mind, could you check whether my second attempt is right or wrong?

Comment: There is no $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\mathbb{R} \subset \bigcup_{j=1}^n [-j,j]$.

Comment: @ProjectBook Now I have no idea how to proceed; could you explain how can I complete the proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be some more efficient way, I don't know, but here I go.

$X = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \overline{A_n}$, $X$ is a complete metric space, it is of second category hence there is $M \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\overline{A_M}$ contains an open set (by definition of "second category"), hence $B(x,r) \subset \overline{A_M}$ for some $x \in X$, $r > 0$.

For $x, y \in \overline{A_M}$, $x = \lim x^n$, $y = \lim y^n$ for $(x^n), (y^n) \subset A_M$ (metric space). For any $n$, $x^n = x^n_1 -  x^n_2$, $y^n = y^n_1 - y^n_2$, for some $x^n_i, y^n_i \in {A \cap \overline{B(0,M)}}$ (definition of $A_M$), then $x^n - y^n = (x^n_1 + y^n_2) - (x^n_2 + y^n_1)$, and $|x^n_1 + y^n_2| \leq 2M$, $\frac{1}{2}(x^n_1 + y^n_2) \in A$ (by definition of $A$) hence $\frac{1}{2}(x^n - y^n) \in A_M$, so that $\frac{1}{2}(x - y) = \lim \frac{1}{2}(x^n - y^n) \in \overline{A_M}$.

Therefore $B(0,r/2) \subset \frac{1}{2}(B(x,r) - x) \subset \overline{A_M}$. Now note that $nA_M \subset A_{nM}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (by definition), hence $n\overline{A_M} \subset \overline{A_{nM}}$ (continuity). For sufficiently large $n_0$, $B(0,1) \subset n_0 B(0,r/2) \subset \overline{A_{n_0 M}}$ and we are done.

Comment: Thank you so much! :) Your idea is clear.